# Counting rows with a window function

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, distinct, window-functions

Each customer can have one or multiple accounts (`account_id`).
To find customer churn, all accounts attached to a customer must be closed, i.e. having `closed_date`

e.g. here customer churn is 2.

How can I get the customer churn in Postgres?
Thanks in advance!

```
+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| customer_id | account_id | created_date | closed_date |
+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
| 3eba3       | 5dddd      | 17/06/2020   |             |
| 3eba3       | eabbd      | 29/06/2020   |             |
| 3eba3       | 9f3a4      | 29/06/2020   | 09/11/2020  |
| 5hlf1       | khti1      | 01/02/2020   |             |
| hdk12       | sfsf2      | 05/03/2020   | 01/06/2020  |
| hdk12       | sfsl3      | 06/03/2020   | 01/06/2020  |
| 12kju       | gege1      | 07/03/2020   | 01/07/2020  |
| 12kju       | mhfl1      | 08/03/2020   | 03/07/2020  |
+-------------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select customer_id
    from mytable
    group by customer_id
    having bool_and(closed_date is not null)
) t
```

An alternative is `count(distinct)` and `not exists`:

```
select count(distinct customer_id)
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.customer_id = t.customer_id and t1.closed_date is null
)
```

Comment: What if I want to find the number of active customers with the second solution provided? i.e. the customers with at least one open account

Comment: @KadirSenkaya: you would just change `not exists` with `exists`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the count, you can use aggregation:

```
select (count(distinct customer_id) -
        count(distinct customer_id) filter (where closed_date is not null)
       )
from accounts;
```

This counts the number of customers in the data and then subtracts those that have an open account.